# Submitting two radio button type forms on a single page using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 2 forms. I would like both forms to act separately and so on form one I would like to submit the form instantly using AJAX using the radio button. The same also for form 2. I can do this for one form but not two. Is this possible?

```
<form id="poll_form" method="post" action="{{URL::route('poll-update')}}">
fieldset class="polling">  
<input type="radio" name="poll_option" value="1"/>
<input type="radio" name="poll_option" value="2"/>
<input type="text" name="poll_option" value="sometext"/> 
<fieldset>
</form>

<form id="poll_formtwo" method="post" action="{{URL::route('poll-update')}}"> 
<fieldset class="polling">  
<input type="radio" name="poll_option" value="1"/>
<input type="radio" name="poll_option" value="2"/>
<input type="text" name="poll_name" value="sometexttext"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I've tried

JQuery

```
  $('input:radio').change(function(){

       var article = $('#poll_form').serializeArray();
       var url     = $('#poll_form').attr('action');

       $.post(url, article, function(data){
           console.log(data);
       });
    });




 $('input:radio').change(function(){

       var article = $('#poll_formtwo').serializeArray();
       var url     = $('#poll_formtwo').attr('action');

       $.post(url, article, function(data){
           console.log(data);
       });
    });
```

Comment: both of your handlers are running here on any radio button click.better to identify them using ID or name.Does your browser console show any error when radio button is clicked,

Comment: Everytime I click on the second form, its the first form that changes

Comment: you click on any both of your `$('input:radio').change(function(){` will fire because the selector `$('input:radio').` is generic & is listening to both radio buttons.

Comment: you can assign unique ID to each of them & have handlers like `$('#radio1'). & $('#radio2')` where `radio1` is the ID of 1st radio button & `radio2` will be for the 2nd.

Comment: oh yeah thanks techie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.secondRadio').change(function(){

   var article = $('#poll_formtwo').serializeArray();
   var url     = $('#poll_formtwo').attr('action');

   $.post(url, article, function(data){
       console.log(data);
   });
});
```

Add a class to your radio button

```
 <input type="radio" class="secondRadio" name="poll_option" value="3"/>
```

Similarly add class for `first radio` and change `corresponding click function`

**Reason for both form submission:**

You have given **same name to your radio button**. **That makes them as a group**. So change of one radio button triggers both events

**Another way: Without HTML Modification**

```
$('#poll_formtwo input:radio').change(function(){

   var article = $('#poll_formtwo').serializeArray();
   var url     = $('#poll_formtwo').attr('action');

   $.post(url, article, function(data){
       console.log(data);
   });
});
```

**Another way**

```
  $( 'input[name="radio2"]:radio' ).change(function(){})
```

It requires change of radio names.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following.

```
$('input:radio').change(function(){
            var $form = $(this).closest('form')
    var article = $form.serializeArray();
    var url     = $form.attr('action');

   $.post(url, article, function(data){
       console.log(data);
   });
});
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lz30mdL/)